# VueJS - Click event is not triggered as parent event prevaults

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, focus, event-bubbling

I am building a search input that fetchs data from my API and lists it in a dropdown list.

Here is the behavior I want my component to have:

- If I start typing and my API founds data, it opens the dropdown menu and lists it.

  - If I click on one of the elements from the list, it is set as 'activeItem' and the dropdown list closes
  - Else, I can click out of the component (input and dropdown list) and the dropdown list closes
- Else, no dropdown list appears and my input works like a regular text input

My issue has to do with Event Bubbling.

- My list items (from API) have a @click input that set the clicked element as the 'activeItem'.
- My input has both @focusin and @focusout events, that allow me to display or hide the dropdown list.

I can't click the elements in the dropdown list as the @focusout event from the input is being triggered first and closes the list.

```js
import ...

export default {
  components: {
    ...
  },

  props: {
    ...
  },

  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      activeItem: null,
      isFocus: false,
    }
  },

  watch: {
    modelValue: _.debounce(function (newSearchText) {
      ... API Call
    }, 350)
  },

  computed: {
    computedLabel() {
      return this.required ? this.label + '<span class="text-primary-600 font-bold ml-1">*</span>' : this.label;
    },

    value: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', value)
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setActiveItem(item) {
      this.activeItem = item;

      this.$emit('selectItem', this.activeItem);
    },

    resetActiveItem() {
      this.activeItem = null;

      this.isFocus = false;
      this.results = [];

      this.$emit('selectItem', null);
    },
  },

  emits: [
    'selectItem',
    'update:modelValue',
  ],
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="relative">
    <label
        v-if="label.length"
        class="block text-tiny font-bold tracking-wide font-medium text-black/75 mb-1 uppercase"
        v-html="computedLabel"
    ></label>

    <div :class="widthCssClass">
      <div class="relative" v-if="!activeItem">
        <div class="flex items-center text-secondary-800">
          <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              class="h-3.5 w-3.5 ml-4 absolute"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke="currentColor"
              stroke-width="2"
          >
            <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
            />
          </svg>

          <!-- The input that triggers the API call -->
          <input
              class="text-black py-2.5 pr-3.5 pl-10 text-black focus:ring-primary-800 focus:border-primary-800 block w-full rounded sm:text-sm border-gray-300"
              placeholder="Search for anything..."
              type="text"
              @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
              @focusin="isFocus = true"
              @focusout="isFocus = false"
          >
        </div>

       <!-- The Dropdown list -->
        <Card
            class="rounded-t-none shadow-2xl absolute w-full z-10 mt-1 overflow-y-auto max-h-48 px-0 py-0"
            v-if="isFocus && results.length"
        >
          <div class="flow-root">
            <ul role="list" class="divide-y divide-gray-200">

              <!-- API results are displayed here -->
              <li
                  v-for="(result, index) in results"
                  :key="index"
                  @click="setActiveItem(result)" <!-- The event I can't trigger -->
              >
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 cursor-pointer px-4 py-3">
                  <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                    <img
                        class="h-8 w-8 rounded-md ring-2 ring-lighter shadow-lg"
                        :src="result.image ?? this.$page.props.page.defaultImage.url"
                        :alt="result.title"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
                    <p
                        class="truncate text-sm font-medium text-black"
                        :class="{
                          'text-primary-900 font-bold': result.id === activeItem?.id
                        }"
                    >
                      {{ result.title }}
                    </p>
                    <p class="truncate text-sm text-black/75">
                      {{ result.description }}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div v-if="result.action">
                    <Link
                        :href="result.action?.url"
                        class="inline-flex items-center rounded-full border border-gray-300 bg-white px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-black/75 shadow-sm hover:bg-primary-50"
                        target="_blank"
                    >
                      {{ result.action?.text }}
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Card>
      </div>

      <!-- Display the active element, can be ignored for this example -->
      <div v-else>
        <article class="bg-primary-50 border-2 border-primary-800 rounded-md">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 px-4 py-3">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                  class="h-8 w-8 rounded-md ring-2 ring-lighter shadow-lg"
                  :src="activeItem.image ?? this.$page.props.page.defaultImage.url"
                  :alt="activeItem.title"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
              <p class="truncate text-sm font-medium text-black font-bold">
                {{ activeItem.title }}
              </p>
              <p class="truncate text-sm text-black/75 whitespace-pre-wrap">
                {{ activeItem.description }}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
              <AppButton @click.stop="resetActiveItem();" @focusout.stop>
                <svg
                    class="w-5 h-5 text-primary-800"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </AppButton>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is a look at the input:

With API results (can't click the elements):

[image]

When no data is found:

[image]

I tried:

```js
handleFocusOut(e) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget, e.target, e.currentTarget)
    // No matter where I click:
    // e.relatedTarget = null
    // e.target = <input id="search" class="...
    // e.currentTarget = <input id="search" class="...
}
...

<input
    id="search"
    class="..."
    placeholder="Search for anything..."
    type="text"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    @focusin="isFocus = true"
    @focusout="handleFocusOut($event)"
>
```

[image]

The solution:

> relatedTarget will be null if the element you click on is not
> focusable. by adding the tabindex attribute it should make the element
> focusable and allow it to be set as relatedTarget. if you actually
> happen to be clicking on some container or overlay element make sure
> the element being clicked on has that tabindex="0" added to it so you
> can maintain isFocus = true

Thanks to @yoduh for the solution

Comment: Can't you just put the `@focusin` and `@focusout` events on a container that includes both the input and the dropdown list?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work either. Also tried to handle the focus state in a dedicated method but event.target and event.currentTarget return the input and the div I put the event on. Every time. Can't see if the user clicked on an elements outside the component. I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root issue looks to be how the dropdown list is being removed from the DOM as soon as the input loses focus because of the `v-if` on it.

```js
<Card
  v-if="isFocus && results.length"
>
```

This is ok to have, but you'll need to work around it by coming up with a solution that keeps `isFocus` true whether the focus is on the input ***or*** the dropdown. I would suggest your input's `@focusout` to execute a method that only sets `isFocus = false` if the focus event's [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) is not any of the dropdown items (can be determined via classname or other attribute). One roadblock to implementing this is that some elements aren't natively focusable, like `<li>` items, so they won't be set as the relatedTarget, but you can *make* them focusable by adding the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute.  Putting it all together should look something like this:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  @focusin="isFocus = true"
  @focusout="loseFocus($event)"
/>

...

<li
  v-for="(result, index) in results"
  :key="index"
  class="listResult"
  tabindex="0"
  @click="setActiveItem(result)"
>
```

```js
loseFocus(event) {
  if (event.relatedTarget?.className !== 'listResult') {
    this.isFocus = false;
  }
}
setActiveItem(item) {
  this.activeItem = item;
  this.isFocus = false;
  this.$emit('selectItem', this.activeItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. event.relatedTarget is always null in my case. And event.target and event.currentTarget return the input text, no matter where I click.

Comment: `relatedTarget` will be null if the element you click on is not focusable.  by adding the `tabindex` attribute it should make the element focusable and allow it to be set as `relatedTarget`.  if you actually happen to be clicking on some container or overlay element make sure the element being clicked on has that `tabindex="0"` added to it so you can maintain `isFocus = true`

Comment: Damn, this tabindex thing is crazy. I had no idea it would prevent my element from being set as relatedTarget. Thanks man, it fixes my prob.