# Vue: Input Manual Autocomplete component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, event-handling, vue-cli

I have a vue-cli project, that has a component named 'AutoCompleteList.vue' that manually handled for searching experience and this component has some buttons that will be fill out the input.

It listens an array as its item list. so when this array has some items, it will be automatically shown; and when I empty this array, it will be automatically hidden.

I defined an `oninput` event method for my `input`, that `fetch`es data from server, and fill the array. so the autocomplete list, will not be shown while the user doesn't try to enter something into the input.

I also like to hide the autocomplete list when the user blurs the input (`onblur`).

but there is a really big problem! when the user chooses one of items (`button`s) on the autocomplete list, JS-engine first blurs the input (`onblur` runs) and then, tries to run `onclick` method in autocomplete list. but its too late, because the autocomplete list has hidden and there is nothing to do. so the input will not fill out...

---

here is my code:

`src/views/LoginView.vue`:

```html
<template>

<InputGroup
    label="Your School Name"
    inputId="schoolName"
    :onInput="schoolNameOnInput"
    autoComplete="off"
    :onFocus="onFocus"
    :onBlur="onBlur"
    :vModel="schoolName"
    @update:vModel="newValue => schoolName = newValue"
/>

<AutoCompleteList
    :items="autoCompleteItems"
    :choose="autoCompleteOnChoose"
    v-show="autoCompleteItems.length > 0"
    :positionY="autoCompletePositionY"
    :positionX="autoCompletePositionX"
/>

</template>

<script>

import InputGroup from '../components/InputGroup'
import AutoCompleteList from '../components/AutoCompleteList'

export default {
    name: 'LoginView',
    components: {
        InputGroup,
        AutoCompleteList
    },
    props: [],
    data: () => ({
        autoCompleteItems: [],
        autoCompletePositionY: 0,
        autoCompletePositionX: 0,
        schoolName: ""
    }),
    methods: {
        async schoolNameOnInput(e) {
            const data = await (await fetch(`http://[::1]:8888/schools/${e.target.value}`)).json();

            this.autoCompleteItems = data;
        },
        autoCompleteOnChoose(value, name) {
            OO("#schoolName").val(name);
            this.schoolName = name;
        },
        onFocus(e) {
            const position = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.autoCompletePositionX = innerWidth - position.right;
            this.autoCompletePositionY = position.top + e.target.offsetHeight + 20;
        },
        onBlur(e) {
            // this.autoCompleteItems = [];
            // PROBLEM! =================================================================
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

---

`src/components/AutoCompleteList.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div class="autocomplete-list" :style="'top: ' + this.positionY + 'px; right: ' + this.positionX + 'px;'">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <button @click="choose(item.value, item.name)" type="button">{{ item.name }}</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'AutoCompleteList',
    props: {
        items: Array,
        positionX: Number,
        positionY: Number,
        choose: Function
    },
    data: () => ({

    })
}

</script>
```

---

`src/components/InputGroup.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label class="input-group-text" :for="inputId ?? ''">{{ label }}</label>
        <input
            :type="type ?? 'text'"
            :class="['form-control', ltr && 'ltr']"
            :id="inputId ?? ''"
            @input="$event => { $emit('update:vModel', $event.target.value); onInput($event); }"
            :autocomplete="autoComplete ?? 'off'"
            @focus="onFocus"
            @blur="onBlur"
            :value="vModel"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'input-group',
    props: {
        label: String,
        ltr: Boolean,
        type: String,
        inputId: String,
        groupingId: String,
        onInput: Function,
        autoComplete: String,
        onFocus: Function,
        onBlur: Function,
        vModel: String
    },
    emits: [
        'update:vModel'
    ],
    data: () => ({

    }),
    methods: {
        
    }
}

</script>
```

---

**Notes on `LoginView.vue`**:

1. `autoCompletePositionX` and `autoCompletePositionY` are used to find the best position to show the autocomplete list; will be changed in `onFocus` method of the `input` (`inputGroup`)
2. `OO("#schoolName").val(name)` is used to change the value of the input, works like `jQuery` (but not exactly)
3. the `[::1]:8888` is my server that used to fetch the search results

---

If there was any unclear code, ask me in the comment

I need to fix this. any idea?

Comment: I think clearing the entire list on blur is a bit premature.  What if the user wants to reclick the input and see the list again? They'd have to delete and retype their query which is not good UX.  There was a question like this asked recently that used a boolean to display the list whenever the input is focused that seemed to work well after solving a different issue (keeping the boolean true while focus switched to a list item so the onclick method could activate), you should study the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75303973) carefully. Hopefully it helps you

Comment: Are you telling me that I should define a property named 'isFocus', default: false?

Comment: as a step 1, yes.  and use that property to control the showing/hiding of your results list

Comment: I think you mean that I should change this value when the user focuses/blurs the input. I did it. but it didn't work correctly. as I said, when the dropdown hides, it cannot run the `onclick` event. it could have any reasons, no differences. it hides and nothing will run.

Comment: I know I should do something to make a difference between clicking on the dropdown and focusing out the input normally. but how?

Comment: see the code posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304731/6225326).  the goal is for your `isFocus` boolean to be true when the input is focused OR when the dropdown is focused, so that if the focus switches between the two you can activate onclick methods and the like.  This can be accomplished by checking the `relatedTarget` when the focus changes (relatedTarget however will be undefined if the dropdown items don't have the `tabindex="0"` attribute). It's explained more in-depth in the linked answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @yoduh

I got the answer.

I knew there should be some differences between when the user focus out the input normally, and when he tries to click on buttons.

the key, was the `FocusEvent.relatedTarget` property. It should be defined in `onblur` method. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) is its full tutorial.

I defined a property named `isFocus` and I change it in `onBlur` method, only when I sure that the focus is not on the dropdown menu, by checking the `relatedTarget`